# Show that $\bigg|\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z^2-1}dz\bigg| \leq \frac{\pi}{3}$, $\gamma$ a quarter of the circle $|z|=2$

Tags: complex-analysis

In particular, $\gamma$ is a section of the circle $2e^{i\theta}$ in the first quadrant (from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$).

I let $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2-1}$. Then $f(\gamma(\theta)) = \frac{1}{4e^{2i\theta}-1}$ and $\gamma'(\theta) = 2ie^{i\theta}$.

Now I use the fact that $\bigg|\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz\bigg| \leq \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\bigg|f(\gamma(\theta))\bigg|\bigg|\gamma'(\theta)\bigg| d\theta$

Therefore $\bigg|\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz\bigg| \leq \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\bigg|\frac{1}{4e^{2i\theta}-1}\bigg|\bigg|2ie^{i\theta}\bigg| d\theta =  \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{\bigg|4e^{2i\theta}-1\bigg|} d\theta$.

Now I need to prove that $\bigg|4e^{2i\theta}-1\bigg| \geq 3$ for $\theta \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$. I do this by showing that $\bigg|4e^{2i\theta}-1\bigg| = \sqrt{(4\cos(2\theta)-1)^2 + (4\sin(2\theta))^2} = \sqrt{17 - 8\cos(2\theta)}$ which is an increasing function, Since $8\cos(2\theta)$ is decreasing on the interval $\theta \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$. Therefore $\bigg|4e^{2i\theta}-1\bigg| \geq \bigg|4e^{2i0}-1\bigg| = 3$.

Then $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{\bigg|4e^{2i\theta}-1\bigg|} d\theta \leq \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2}{3} d\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$.

Could some users please confirm whether my proof is correct? I would also be interested to know if there is a better way to prove this that doesn't involve converting the complex number from exponential form, since I feel like by doing this I might have missed the point of the exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is fine. Here is an easier way to prove the required inequality: By the reverse triangle inequality, we have

$$|z^2-1| \geq |z^2| -1 = |z|^2 -1$$

for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$. As $z=\gamma(\theta)$ satisfies $|z|=2$, this shows

$$|\gamma(\theta)^2-1| \geq 2^2-1 = 3.$$